# Excel VBA Type Mismatch (13)

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting a type mismatch error in VBA and I am not sure why.

The purpose of this macro is to go through a column in an Excel spreadsheet and add all the emails to an array. After each email is added to the first array, it's also supposed to added to a second array but split into two pieces at the `@` symbol in order to separate name from domain. Like so: `person@gmail.com` to `person` and `gmail.com`.

The problem that I'm getting is that when it gets to the point where it's supposed to split the email, it throws a Type Mismatch error.

Specifically this part:

`strDomain = Split(strText, "@")`

Here is the complete code:

```
Sub addContactListEmails()
    Dim strEmailList() As String    'Array of emails
    Dim blDimensioned As Boolean    'Is the array dimensioned?
    Dim strText As String           'To temporarily hold names
    Dim lngPosition As Long         'Counting

    Dim strDomainList() As String
    Dim strDomain As String
    Dim dlDimensioned As Boolean
    Dim strEmailDomain As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Dim countRows As Long
    'countRows = Columns("E:E").SpecialCells(xlVisible).Rows.Count
    countRows = Range("E:E").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    MsgBox "The number of rows is " & countRows

    'The array has not yet been dimensioned:
    blDimensioned = False

    Dim counter As Long
    Do While counter < countRows
        counter = counter + 1

        ' Set the string to the content of the cell
        strText = Cells(counter, 5).Value

        If strText <> "" Then

            'Has the array been dimensioned?
            If blDimensioned = True Then

                'Yes, so extend the array one element large than its current upper bound.
                'Without the "Preserve" keyword below, the previous elements in our array would be erased with the resizing
                ReDim Preserve strEmailList(0 To UBound(strEmailList) + 1) As String

            Else

                'No, so dimension it and flag it as dimensioned.
                ReDim strEmailList(0 To 0) As String
                blDimensioned = True

            End If

            'Add the email to the last element in the array.
            strEmailList(UBound(strEmailList)) = strText

            'Also add the email to the separation array
            strDomain = Split(strText, "@")
            If strDomain <> "" Then
                    If dlDimensioned = True Then
                        ReDim Preserve strDomainList(0 To UBound(strDomainList) + 1) As String
                    Else
                        ReDim strDomainList(0 To 0) As String
                        dlDimensioned = True
                    End If
                strDomainList(UBound(strDomainList)) = strDomain
            End If

        End If

    Loop


    'Display email addresses, TESTING ONLY!

    For lngPosition = LBound(strEmailList) To UBound(strEmailList)

        MsgBox strEmailList(lngPosition)

    Next lngPosition

    For i = LBound(strDomainList) To UBound(strDomainList)

        MsgBox strDomainList(strDomain)

    Next

    'Erase array
    'Erase strEmailList

End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ReDim`ing arrays is a big hassle. Welcome to the world of `collection`s and `Dictionary`s.  [Collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collection_%28computing%29#Lists) objects are always accessible. [Dictionaries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) require a reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` (Tools>References>scroll down to find that text and check the box> OK). They dynamically change size for you, you can add, remove items very easily compared to arrays, and Dictionaries especially allow you to organize your data in more logical ways.

In the below code I used a dictionary there the key is the domain (obtained with the split function). Each `value` for a `key` is a collection of email addresses with that domain.

Put a break point on `End Sub` and look at the contents of each of these objects in your locals window. I think you'll see they make more sense and are easier in general.

Option Explicit

```
Function AllEmails() As Dictionary

    Dim emailListCollection As Collection
    Set emailListCollection = New Collection 'you're going to like collections way better than arrays
    Dim DomainEmailDictionary As Dictionary
    Set DomainEmailDictionary = New Dictionary 'key value pairing. key is the domain. value is a collection of emails in that domain
    Dim emailParts() As String
    Dim countRows As Long
    Dim EmailAddress As String
    Dim strDomain As String

    'countRows = Columns("E:E").SpecialCells(xlVisible).Rows.Count
    Dim sht As Worksheet 'always declare your sheets!
    Set sht = Sheets("Sheet1")

    countRows = sht.Range("E2").End(xlDown).Row

    Dim counter As Long
    Do While counter < countRows
        counter = counter + 1

        EmailAddress = Trim(sht.Cells(counter, 5))

        If EmailAddress <> "" Then

            emailParts = Split(EmailAddress, "@")
            If UBound(emailParts) > 0 Then
                strDomain = emailParts(1)
            End If

            If Not DomainEmailDictionary.Exists(strDomain) Then
                'if you have not already encountered this domain
                DomainEmailDictionary.Add strDomain, New Collection
            End If

            'Add the email to the dictionary of emails organized by domain
            DomainEmailDictionary(strDomain).Add EmailAddress

            'Add the email to the collection of only addresses
            emailListCollection.Add EmailAddress
        End If
    Loop

    Set AllEmails = DomainEmailDictionary
End Function
```

and use it with

```
Sub RemoveUnwantedEmails()

    Dim allemailsDic As Dictionary, doNotCallSheet As Worksheet, emailsSheet As Worksheet
    Set doNotCallSheet = Sheets("DoNotCallList")
    Set emailsSheet = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set allemailsDic = AllEmails

    Dim domain As Variant, EmailAddress As Variant
    Dim foundDoNotCallDomains As Range, emailAddressesToRemove   As Range

    For Each domain In allemailsDic.Keys
        Set foundDoNotCallDomains = doNotCallSheet.Range("A:A").Find(domain)
        If Not foundDoNotCallDomains Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print "domain found"
            'do your removal
            For Each EmailAddress In allemailsDic(domain)
                Set emailAddressesToRemove = emailsSheet.Range("E:E").Find(EmailAddress)
                If Not emailAddressesToRemove Is Nothing Then
                    emailAddressesToRemove = ""
                 End If
            Next EmailAddress
        End If
    Next domain

End Sub
```

Comment: `Compile Error, Type Mismatch` at `If strDomain <> "" Then`

Comment: Yes, there is a lot going on here. I will have a much more comprehensive answer in a minute

Comment: Do collections make it easier to compare with another sheet and return matches?

Comment: That's a pretty open-ended question with a lot going on. Collections, like arrays, have nothing to do with the `Sheet` or matching things together. Collections are a tool you can use to accomplish that task (so are `Ranges`). It depends on where you're going with this. In general I'd say yes/don't use an array but rather use the ranges themselves.

Comment: My goal is to get the domains from every email in Sheet1, the Contact List, and compare to a list of domains in Sheet2, the Do Not Contact sheet. So if out of 10 emails for example, 2 of the domains in Sheet1 match a domain in Sheet2, they are removed from Sheet1. What would be the simplest method of getting the comparison done?

Comment: See my edit. You can see how quick collections and dictionaries made that :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19310/discussion-between-thiago-m-and-brad)

Answer (score 4):

strDomain must store array of the split text, therefore,

```
Dim strDomain As Variant
```

Afterwards, strDomain should be referenced by index, if operations with certain fragments will be made:

```
If strDomain(i) <> "" Then
```

Answer (score 2):

The *split* function returns an array of strings based on the provided separator.

In your if you are sure that the original string is an email, with just one "@" in it then you can safely use the below code:

```
strDomain = Split(strText, "@")(1)
```

This will get you the part after "@" which is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

`Split` returns an array:

```
Dim mailComp() As String
[...]
mailComp = Split(strText, "@")
strDomain = mailComp(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `strDomain = Split(strText,"@")(1)` to get the right hand side of the split where `(0)` would be the left. And of course works with more than 2 splits as well. You could dim you string variable as an array `strDomain()` and then `Split(strText,"@")` will place all the seperated text into the array.